# Censoring/masking the text python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have text arranged in a pandas dataframe. The text contains people names which i need to mask/censor. I have used spacy and got the names in a list and i have to mask those names and create the masked text in another column. and it should iterate over the dataframe. Need a python 3 solution

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create custom function with replace and pass it to list comprehension or to `apply` method with `re.sub` and words boundaries:

```
import re
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':1, 
                   'Note_Text':[ 'I served Mr. Mutiso, a ginger. Me, Julia. Linger'],
                   'Name_List':[['Mutiso','Julia','Linger']]})

def censor(text,L):
    for x in L:
        text = re.sub(r"\b{}\b".format(x), x[0] + (len(x)-1)*'*',text)
    return text


df['Censored_text1'] = [censor(a, b) for a,b in zip(df['Note_Text'], df['Name_List'])]
df['Censored_text2']  = df.apply(lambda x: censor(x['Note_Text'], x['Name_List']), axis=1)
print (df)
   ID                                         Note_Text  \
0   1  I served Mr. Mutiso, a ginger. Me, Julia. Linger   

                 Name_List                                    Censored_text1  \
0  [Mutiso, Julia, Linger]  I served Mr. M*****, a ginger. Me, J****. L*****   

                                     Censored_text2  
0  I served Mr. M*****, a ginger. Me, J****. L*****
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to split your text and replace where items from your list are in the returned list, then join back to string.

Example:

```
your_text = "After takeoff i served Mr. Mutiso a schotch and ginger ale. His seat mate, Julia ....."

name_list = [ "Mutiso", "Julia" ]
spl_str = your_text.split( " " )

for i in range( 0, len( spl_str) ):

    if spl_str[i] in name_list:
        spl_str[i] = "*******"

new_string = (" ").join( spl_str )

print(new_string)
```

```
Output: After takeoff i served Mr. ******* a schotch and ginger ale. His seat mate, ******* .....
```

Attention:
    On your_text.split(' ') we assume that there is no situation like Julia.
 It work for Julia( space ). becouse you split at empty space and if a name is near a dot or something like that then it wont work. After split you could try a trim or something like that.

Comment: the only thing I will change in your answer is the length of * is fixed I might think that needs to be dynamic accordingly.

Comment: Yes i like it better. it was a fast answer and i'm not a really experienced programmer.

Comment: me neither. it would be more sophisticated if the solution is more dynamic that's what I alway's thought when writing a solution.

Answer (score 0):

this is what i understand from your question you have a list of names and a string that has those names and you want to mask those names with * .That exact thing can be done by the below code.

```
    text = "After takeoff i served Mr. Mutiso a schotch and ginger ale. His seat mate, Julia ....."
    name_list = [ "Mutiso", "Julia" ]

    for i in name_list:
        text = text.replace(i,str(len(i)*"*"))

    print(text)
```

The number of * in the output depends on the length of the name.

Comment: Thanks, if i want to do the same with some thing like one less than the length. for example Mutiso becomes M***** and Julia becomes J****  in the final string ?